# Bootstrap multiselect with icheck plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using both **[Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)** and **[iCheck](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/)** . It's Looking fine but After adding iCheck, Multiselect is not working how it should. On Multiselect if I select Select all , all the option become selected. But after adding iCheck it not doing that functionality and also other functionality too. Just doing regular Check.

is here How it looks:
[image]

This is How I call the Multiselect:

```
     $('.multiselect').multiselect({
       includeSelectAllOption: true,
       buttonWidth: '100%',
       nonSelectedText: 'Select multiple option'
    });
```

This is How I call the iCheck:

```
     $('input').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'checkbox-default',
      radioClass: 'radio-default',
     });
```

Is there anything Extra I need to add or Do ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

i dig a little bit, it seems to be ok with version 2 of icheck

/////link: https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/blob/2.x-beta/icheck.js

the owner changed the url to: https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/tree/2.x

currently v2 is beta, i dont have enought time to test it right now complatly, but it seems fine.